# Vertx stop method not executed on service stop

Tags: vert.x, shutdown-hook, vertx-verticle

When I stop the service the stop is not getting called but if try the same in test case where I deploy and undeploy verticle with deployment ID the stop method is executing.

EDIT:-
I am creating jar file (not a shadow Jar).
Below is build.gradle configuration

```
application{
    mainClassName='io.vertx.core.Launcher'
}

def mainVerticleName = 'verticleName'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                "Manifest-Version": "1.0",
                "Main-Verticle": "$mainVerticleName",
                "Main-Class": "io.vertx.core.Launcher",
                "Class-Path": configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ')
        )
    }
}
```

starting application :-

```
java -jar api-gateway-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dconfig.propertyFile="<property file path>" -DlogfilePath="<log file path>"
```

stopping application :-

**CTRL+C**

Comment: Please include more context about how you package, start and stop the app when not running a test case

Comment: How do you "stop the service"? Are you just terminating your JVM process?

Comment: No, I am not terminating jvm process, Updated in quetion

Comment: @tsegismont I have updated the question

Comment: I can't see anything obvisouly wrong. Can you file an issue with a simple reproducer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating CustomLauncher extending Launcher class worked.

```
@Log4j2
public class CustomLauncher extends Launcher {
   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CustomLauncher().dispatch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStoppingVertx(Vertx vertx) {
        log.info(" beforeStoppingVertx Called ===========");
       cleanUPBeforeStoppingVerx();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterStoppingVertx() {
        log.info(" afterStoppingVertx Called ===========");
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeDeployingVerticle(DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions) {
        log.info(" beforeDeployingVerticle Called ===========");
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStartingVertx(VertxOptions options) {
        log.info(" beforeStartingVertx Called ===========");
    }

   
    @Override
    public void afterStartingVertx(Vertx vertx) {
        log.info(" afterStartingVertx Called ===========");
    }

    @Override
    public void handleDeployFailed(Vertx vertx, String mainVerticle, DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions,
                                   Throwable cause) {
        log.info("handleDeployFailed *****************");
        vertx.close();
    }
}
```

build.gradle changes :-

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                "Manifest-Version": "1.0",
                "Main-Verticle": "LauncherVerticle",
                "Main-Class": "CustomLauncher",
                "Class-Path": configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ')
        )
    }
}
```